# How to remove the rows while using add more functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I want to make add more functionality, if I am clicking add more button means I want to make a copy of one row it is working fine, but again I want to remove this row means I don't how to do? if I am clicking remove button I want to remove the selected row, not for all rows, I am a new person of development anyone means please update my snippet

```js
var i=0;
$(document).on("click",".addSharingType",function() {
  i++;
 
  var htmlText = '';
  htmlText += '<div class="controls"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> <label>Sharing Type</label><select class="form-control seelectcss1 border" name="sharingType[]" required=""><option value="">Select</option><option value="Single Sharing">Single Sharing</option><option value="Two Sharing">Two Sharing</option><option value="Three Sharing">Three Sharing</option><option value="Four Sharing">Four Sharing</option></select></div></div><div class="row entry"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><label class="control-label">Rent With Food :</label><br><input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withFood[]" id="withfood" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)"> <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"> <div id="word"></div><p class="custom-error amountError" style="display:none">Please Enter Amount</p></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><label class="control-label">Rent Without Food </label><br><input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withoutFood[]" id="withoutfood" onkeyup="word1.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)"> <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word1"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><label class="control-label">Advance Amount</label><br><input type="number" class="form-control  nput border" name="advance[]" id="advance" onkeyup="word2.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)"><img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word2"></div></div></div>';
   
  htmlText +='<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success addSharingType" style="margin-top: 26px;height: 38px;" id="admore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger addSharingType" style="margin-top: 26px;height: 38px;" id="admore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> remove</button></div></div>';
   
  htmlText +='</div></div>';
  htmlText +='</div><br>';
  $('.sharingType').append(htmlText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="controls">
  <div class="row">      
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> 
      <label>Sharing Type</label>
      <select class="form-control seelectcss1 border" name="sharingType[]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Single Sharing">Single Sharing</option>
        <option value="Two Sharing">Two Sharing</option>
        <option value="Three Sharing">Three Sharing</option>
        <option value="Four Sharing">Four Sharing</option>
      </select>       
    </div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="row entry">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <label class="control-label">Rent With Food :</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withFood[]" id="withfood" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)"> 
        <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"> <div id="word"></div>     
        <p class="custom-error amountError" style="display:none">Please Enter Amount</p>  
     </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <label class="control-label">Rent Without Food </label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withoutFood[]" id="withoutfood" onkeyup="word1.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)"> 
        <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <label class="control-label">Advance Amount</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control  nput border" name="advance[]" id="advance" onkeyup="word2.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)">
        <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word2"></div>     
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success addSharingType" style="margin-top: 26px;height: 38px;" id="admore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Sharing</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sharingType"></div>
```

Comment: You should not make DOM elements by using a string literal. It's neither hard to read your code nor not a recommended way to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change remove button class from `addSharingType` to `removeSharingType` and then apply this code:-

```
$(document).on("click",".removeSharingType",function() {
 $(this).closest('.controls').remove();
});
```

***Working example:-***

```js
var i=0;
$(document).on("click",".addSharingType",function() {
  i++;
 
  var htmlText = '';
  htmlText += '<div class="controls"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> <label>Sharing Type</label><select class="form-control seelectcss1 border" name="sharingType[]" required=""><option value="">Select</option><option value="Single Sharing">Single Sharing</option><option value="Two Sharing">Two Sharing</option><option value="Three Sharing">Three Sharing</option><option value="Four Sharing">Four Sharing</option></select></div></div><div class="row entry"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><label class="control-label">Rent With Food :</label><br><input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withFood[]" id="withfood" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)"> <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"> <div id="word"></div><p class="custom-error amountError" style="display:none">Please Enter Amount</p></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><label class="control-label">Rent Without Food </label><br><input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withoutFood[]" id="withoutfood" onkeyup="word1.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)"> <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word1"></div></div></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><label class="control-label">Advance Amount</label><br><input type="number" class="form-control  nput border" name="advance[]" id="advance" onkeyup="word2.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)"><img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word2"></div></div></div>';
   
  htmlText +='<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div class="form-group" id="imm"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success addSharingType" style="margin-top: 26px;height: 38px;" id="admore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removeSharingType" style="margin-top: 26px;height: 38px;" id="admore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> remove</button></div></div>';
   
  htmlText +='</div></div>';
  htmlText +='</div><br>';
  $('.sharingType').append(htmlText);
});

$(document).on("click",".removeSharingType",function() {
  $(this).closest('.controls').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="controls">
  <div class="row">      
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> 
      <label>Sharing Type</label>
      <select class="form-control seelectcss1 border" name="sharingType[]" required="">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="Single Sharing">Single Sharing</option>
        <option value="Two Sharing">Two Sharing</option>
        <option value="Three Sharing">Three Sharing</option>
        <option value="Four Sharing">Four Sharing</option>
      </select>       
    </div>
  </div>
      
  <div class="row entry">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <label class="control-label">Rent With Food :</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withFood[]" id="withfood" onkeyup="word.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)"> 
        <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"> <div id="word"></div>     
        <p class="custom-error amountError" style="display:none">Please Enter Amount</p>  
     </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:5px;">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <label class="control-label">Rent Without Food </label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control nput border" name="withoutFood[]" id="withoutfood" onkeyup="word1.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)"> 
        <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <label class="control-label">Advance Amount</label>
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control  nput border" name="advance[]" id="advance" onkeyup="word2.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords1(this.value)">
        <img src="image/rup.png" id="try"><div id="word2"></div>     
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="imm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success addSharingType" style="margin-top: 26px;height: 38px;" id="admore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Sharing</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sharingType"></div>
```

Comment: @MithunM  glad to help you :):) . My current code is working as you expected

Answer (score 0):

@Mithun I am glad you got the answer that you wanted. I did give an attempt to fix you code; But I found it a bit uncomfortable given that you were appending html via javascript (which is never a good practise)

So, I accomplished your requirement (delete rows, clone rows) in pure javascript.

Since you are new to development, may I request that you avoid using libraries right away and try coding in vanilla js. Believe me, this will make you a great developer.

Have a look at my snippet; I hope it gives you an idea of solving the same issue in vanilla js.   Cheers

```js
window.onload = addEventListeners();

function addEventListeners() {
  let cloneButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("clone");
  let deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
  
  for(let button of cloneButtons) {  
     button.onclick = cloneDiv;
  }
  for(let button of deleteButtons) {  
     button.onclick = deleteDiv;
  }
}

function cloneDiv() {
   let wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
   let clonedDiv = wrapper.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
   wrapper.appendChild(clonedDiv);
   addEventListeners();
}

function deleteDiv() {
   let targetDiv = this.closest('.divToClone');
   targetDiv.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="divToClone">
<p>
this line
</p>
<p>
will be
</p>
<p>
cloned or removed
</p>
<p>
based on your choice
</p>
<button class="clone"> Clone row </button>
<button class="delete"> Delete row </button>
</div>
</div>
```